# Installing python 3 modules issues

Tags: drivers, apt, python, python3, python-2.7

I am having an issue installing modules on OS Ubuntu 19.04 with Python 3.7.3 and Python 2.7.16

The module is only for Python>=3.5.

Research hasn't led me to much or I have looked in the wrong places or I am misunderstanding the full error message.

The best I have found is is to avoid removing Python 2 to not mess up other programs that require it and I haven't removed Python 2.  Any help would be appreciated.  See below for more info:

***Current path***

```
/usr/bin/python
```

***Pip command I have tried to use***

```
pip install python-chess
```

***Error***

```
Collecting python-chess
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/ed/ae1dbb45de32df04c9b2cdfa1802bd7509978da1ad245b3180276f5937a6/python-chess-0.24.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-oKceEK/python-chess/setup.py", line 35, in <module>
        """)
    ImportError: You are installing python-chess on Python 2.

    Python 2 support has been dropped. Consider upgrading to Python 3, or using
    the 0.23.x branch, which will be maintained until the end of 2018.


    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-oKceEK/python-chess/
```

Comment: Try `pip3` instead of `pip`.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Analogous to `python` (python 2.7) and `python3` (python 3.X), there's `pip` (python 2.7) and `pip3` (python 3.X).

To install a python3 module, use `pip3`.